# Eslint config to not allow blanket eslint-disable

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there a way to have eslint yell when you have a blanket `/* eslint-disable */` or `// eslint-disable-line` in a file? I would like the disable rules to be as specific as possible.

Comment: one solution would be to simply replace those lines which contain the rules with this webpack plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin.

Comment: you might think about writing your own eslint rule: https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/27/writing-custom-eslint-rules/